# Sproradic MessageLockLostException but lock not expired and is the same MessageReceiver instance

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I've been scratching my head over this for a while.
Most of the time it is working fine, but we get occasional clusters of MessageLockLostException. As far as I can tell the conditions are correct to be able to complete the message.

We are using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver created as follows

```cs
var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(
                            this.ConnectionString,
                            EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath(topicName, subName),
                            ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
```

Here is an example from our log

```
1/7/2020, 11:35:42.689 AM Got message for processing messageId:51c90000ff1c00035d9408d79365b47e, clientId=MessageReceiver20live/delivery-p/Subscriptions/1of1, LockToken:137a02f1-eed7-4b0e-a84b-996d9ede002a, Expiry:1/7/2020 11:40:42 AM, IsLockSet:True
DO STUFF
1/7/2020, 11:36:19.204 AM Complete Message "messageId":"51c90000ff1c00035d9408d79365b47e","clientId":"MessageReceiver20live/delivery-p/Subscriptions/1of1","lockToken":"137a02f1-eed7-4b0e-a84b-996d9ede002a"
1/7/2020, 11:36:19.291 AM Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageLockLostException
```

The exception message is "The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver instance."
But I don't think any of those conditions is true.

1. You can seen above the lock token matches and is not expired.
2. I know the message hasn't already been completed because it gets redelivered a few minutes later (coinciding with the lock expiry)
3. The receiver instances match

Comment: What's the `MaxLockDuration` configure for the queue? Is it 5 minutes or less? If it's too short, this can happen. Is this happening on some messages or all messages received from this queue? Would you be able to share a simple repro via GitHub or similar?

Comment: 5 minutes. I can't repro it locally. It just happens once in a while in production. For example yesterday we had 5 in amongst thousands of messages. Today all fine. Day before yesterday all fine.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the cluster yesterday were all around a similar time. I am wondering if it is something going on at the service bus end.

Comment: Can you share your repro on GitHub? No credentials 

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Ian1971/01fcbed0d855316341731f7620b409be

Comment: For reference we haven't had an instance of this since 7th Jan (7 days ago). That is how uncommon it is.

Comment: On the 7th they all occurred between 11am and 11:40

Comment: The code snippet looks fine. Except when you catch an exception and abandon the message. If the exception is `LockLostException`, you won't be able to abandon as you no longer have the message's lock. I would advise to log the message details and raise a support case with Microsoft/Azure as this doesn't seem to be right at all.

Comment: Thanks. Will do that.

Comment: This is about a year and half later  But I just wanted to confirm that I've seen the same issue (specifically for a subscription on a topic). In my case I can always correlate it with throttling of the Service Bus.

Comment: BTW, did you raise a support case with Azure, and if so, did you get an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are not exceeding your credit based throttling - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-throttling

I am getting lots of these false message lock exceptions even though I have plenty of time left until lock expiry, when trying tests of throughput that must be exceeding my limits. If I then issue a call to try and renew the lock straight after getting the lock exeption (as an expirement) I then receive a server busy exception like this one:

"The request was terminated because the namespace xxxxx is being throttled. Error code : 50009. Please wait 2 seconds and try again."